# Update a file with google drive API Error 403

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gwt, google-drive-api

I currently have a problem with my GWT application which uses Google Cloud.

I actually have a piece of code that allows you to upload a file using the google drive application.
Except that here, with the update of google, it is no longer possible to have several parents for a file on google drive as we can see it here:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/simplifying-google-drives-folder-structure-and-sharing-models

*" You can only add a parent for an item that doesn't already have one. This affects the children.insert (v2), files.update (v2 / v3) and parents.insert (v2) endpoints. You can use the new canAddMyDriveParent capability to check if an item currently has no parents and if the user has sufficient access to add a parent for the item."*

So I have my following piece of code:

```
service.files().update(fileId, file).execute();
```

which generates an error:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Increasing the number of parents is not allowed",
    "reason" : "cannotAddParent"
  } ],
  "message" : "Increasing the number of parents is not allowed"
}
```

But i don't have any idea on how to upload a file, without getting this error.

In fact, i don't know how to create a new parent folder, or if i can upload without a parent.
If any one can help me, any help would be appreciated !

Huge thank !

Comment: whats file?  you can only add one parent.

Comment: I can only add 1 file to 1 parent ?
Or i can set only 1 parent to my file?

EDIT : when i do : service.files().list() it prints : {}
But, when i prints my file i have many infos, like 
"parents":[{"id":"anyId","isRoot":true,"kind":"drive#parentReference","parentLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/anyId","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/anyId/parents/anyId2"},{"id":"anyId2"}]

Comment: Google drive is just  file storage system.   A file can have only one parent directory or it would be in two different places.    A parent can be set as parent to more the one files meaning that it has several children.  parents is singular.

Comment: @DaImTo how can i create a new parent ? Or update my file in another place ?

Comment: you need to create a new folder. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder

Comment: But if create a new folder everytimes, i will have too much folders no ?
Maybe it's much proper to create shortcuts ? right

Comment: you can have more than one file in a folder

Answer (score 2):

The API has changed early this year (2020) when Google introduced [shortcuts](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/simplifying-google-drives-folder-structure-and-sharing-models):

> You can only add a parent for an item that doesn't already have one. This affects the children.insert (v2), files.update (v2 / v3) and parents.insert (v2) endpoints. You can use the new canAddMyDriveParent capability to check if an item currently has no parents and if the user has sufficient access to add a parent for the item.

**This was announced in March but it's been implemented since September 30.**

You guessed right: [Shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts#create_a_shortcut) is the way to replicate a file in different Folders, but take into account they have different characteristics than the original file and they are not a "copy". The MimeType is `application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut`
.

Example of the creation of a Shortcut:

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Project Plan',
    'mimeType': 'text/plain'
}
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
shortcut_metadata = {
     'Name': 'Shortcut to Project Plan',
     'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut',
     'shortcutDetails': {
        'targetId': file.get('id')
     }
}
shortcut = drive_service.files().create(body=shortcut_metadata,
                                    fields='id,shortcutDetails').execute()
print('File ID: %s, Shortcut Target ID: %s, Shortcut Target MIME type: %s' % (
    shortcut.get('id'),
    shortcut.get('shortcutDetails').get('targetId'),
    shortcut.get('shortcutDetails').get('targetMimeType')))
```